# Events are fired one after another when i use a function for columnHeaderText or columnHeaderHtml

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using `fullcalendar` angular plugin, version 4. I need to overwrite column headers dynamically. But when i do it, it seems that calendar is constantly redrawn and all events that i use become unusable. I can not click an event in the calendar, `mouse-enter` and `mouse-leave` events are being fired one after another with microscopic delay even when i just leave cursor over the event.
Has anyone met the same problem?

```
 <full-calendar
      #calendar
      ...
      (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
      (eventClick)="handleEventClick($event)"
      (eventMouseEnter)="eventMouseEnter($event)"
      (eventMouseLeave)="eventMouseLeave($event)"
      ...
      [columnHeaderText]="getDayFunc"
></full-calendar>
```

I expected the function that i put into `[columnHeaderText]` be used maybe one time per view, but not constantly

```js
getDay(arg: Date): string {
    if (this.calendarComponent) {
      const view = this.calendarComponent.getApi().view;
      if (view.viewSpec.type === 'timeGridDay') {
        return this.getDayString(arg.getDay());
      } else if (view.viewSpec.type === 'timeGridWeek') {
        return this.getDayString(arg.getDay(), true);
      } else {
        return this.getDayString(arg.getDay(), true);
      }
    }
    return ' ';
  }
```

When initializing component i set 
`getDayFunc = this.getDay.bind(this)`

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderText) the callback function will be called once per column. It receives the column's date as a parameter, so I'm not sure how you imagined it could be called only once per view...?

Comment: Anyway, if you encountering issues with the use of that function, it would probably make sense to show us the code of that function and explain what you are trying to achieve with it. The code you've shown above does not, by itself, cause any of the problems are you describing.

Comment: The problem is that when i use this function - even with `return ' '` insinde - i am not able to use any events - for example i tried to log what is happening with `eventMouseEnter` and `eventMouseLeave` - they are fired just one after another when mouse is over an event.

Comment: If you are saying that declaring the function with nothing but `return ' '` in it causes the error, then I wonder if the problem is something internal to fullCalendar...perhaps you should raise a bug with the fullCalendar maintainers instead